# Inherit generic class keeping generics and retrieve generic type in parent

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class which generics and tried to extend it passing through the generics.
But it seems that it isn't possible to get the generic type anymore.

The root class

```
public abstract class AbstractDataModel<T extends AbstractEntity> extends DataModel<T> {

    private final Class<T> rootType;

    protected AbstractDataModel() {
        Type genericSuperclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType)genericSuperclass;
        Type type = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        rootType = (Class<T>)type;
    }
```

The specialization

```
public class OwnerDataModel<T extends AbstractEntity> extends AbstractDataModel<T> {
```

I get an exception when casting **type** to `Class<T>`. I got

> Cannot cast 'sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl'
>   to 'java.lang.Class'

Normally I am using the *AbstractDataModel* directly

```
dataModel = new AbstractDataModel<Entity>() {
```

And I want to use my *OwnerDataModel* like the following

```
dataModel = new OwnerDataModel<Entity>();
```

What did I miss?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: What kind of exception you've got ?

Comment: Just as a warning, it looks like you are diving deep into generics, and it my experience, it has never worked out.  Just when you think you have things working, you seem to always get bitten by generic erasures.  So, if you could do this with less generics, I would recommend giving that another look.

Comment: `AbstractDataModel` is an abstract class you can't instantiate

Comment: not all `Type`s are `Class`es

Comment: Added exception message. @ControlAltDel If I don't inherit the class it works like expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get generic type of class at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: @px5x2 Not really a duplicate. I am using inheritance in comparison to your posted link.

Comment: Please see other than 2nd answer. Especially 3rd one and its comments, imo it adresses to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have to write this :

```
public class OwnerDataModel<T extends AbstractEntity> extends AbstractDataModel<T> { ...
```

but this : `public class OwnerDataModel extends AbstractDataModel<T> { ...`

because, is included in the first by default by `AbstractDataModel<T>`.

Second, 
You can't instantiate `AbstractDataModel` but the class `OwnerDataModel` .

Comment: But T is a generic. It doesn't compile like you suggested.